# Problem with flatbuffer compilation and installation while installing cnosdb

Tags: flatbuffers, cnosdb

When installing cnosdb, I was prompted by the official website to download, compile and install flatbuffer first, but the following error occurred during the installation process.

My system information is as follows:

```
Linux cnos17 3.10.0-1160.81.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Dec 16 17:29:43 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My version of cmake is as follows:

```
cmake --version
cmake version 3.16.0

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

My build and install command is as follows:

```
git clone -b v22.9.29 --depth 1 https://github.com/google/flatbuffers.git && cd flatbuffers
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
sudo make install
```

How can I modify the compilation and installation command to solve this problem:

```
error: unused parameter ‘tests_data_path’ [-Werror=unused-parameter]
 void TestMonsterExtraFloats(const std::string &tests_data_path) {
      ^
cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/flattests.dir/tests/monster_test.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/flattests.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: That is just the an aggressive warning in the tests. You can either just make `flatc` and not `flattests`. Or disable the `-Werror=unused-parameter` setting. We can probably not make that an error by default: https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L397